# how to display clickble cart with badge on menu bar in android

Tags: android

I am created a shopping cart and  want to display the badge with number of product selected in cart on menu. on click of cart icon it should go to cart page where i display all the products in list.

Comment: but it is not clickable. i want clickable badge

Comment: Add a `clicklistener` to it to make it clickable.

Comment: when i remove app:actionlayout from menu file, at that time clicklistener  working otherwise not working

Comment: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem by using button onclick event.
i placed cart image as button background and changing the text of cart.
[image: Button with text]

Menu item code :

`<item
        android:id="@+id/item_samplebadge"
        android:title="Cart"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/budge_layout"/>`

Budge_layoout.xml (actionLayout:@layout/budge_layout)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cart"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"/>
```

in fragment calling onclick event

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_order_process,menu);
    this.mMenu=menu;

    RelativeLayout v=(RelativeLayout)menu.findItem(R.id.item_samplebadge).getActionView();

    Button count1=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    int cartsize=aController.getProductsArrayListSize();

    count1.setText(String.valueOf(cartsize));

    count1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            budge_click();
        }
    });

}
```

this code worked for my application